# How can I use webrtc offline

Tags: firefox, webrtc, rtsp, stun

I'm developing a Vuejs app that among other things displays several RTSP streams in the browser.
For converting the streams and displaying them I'm using [RTSPtoWebRTC](https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWebRTC) with [WebRtcPlayer](https://github.com/vdalex25/WebRtcPlayer).
I decided to use WebRTC because of the low latency (this is a robotics project).
This method is working fine and I can view all the streams with a max latency of 50ms.
But as soon as I disconnect from the internet I get an error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Can't create RTCPeerConnections when the network is down
```

I cant count that this robot will have an internet connection at all time, this isnt the intent.

I tried several solutions like removing any mention of external iceServers from the player and the server.

```
      iceServers: [{
        urls: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]
      }]
```

Tried running my own STUN/TURN server with coturn and supplying the ip address as an ICE server but to no success - still same no internet error.

I'm running the app on Firefox if this matters and I found this post from a while back: [firefox bug report about this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=831926)

I tried the suggestion there of trying to set media.peerconnection.ice.loopback in about:config to true but still doesn't work.

Help is much appreciated!

Edit:

So, after spending too many hours trying to solve this I found that in Chrome this works offline just fine. So I’ll just stick to that

Comment: you're disconnecting from the internet by a bespoke browser setting?
try pulling the cable from your router -- things should still work assuming a local signalling server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error gets thrown here in Firefox code: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/media/PeerConnection.jsm#473

The workaround with the loopback interface no longer works if I read that code correct. The if condition in the code just asks the networking code if there is any network connectivity.

So you either

- try Phillips suggestion of making one network interface believe it still has connectivity. Maybe a fake interface with a hard coded IP address, but no default route would be enough.
- Or you convince the Mozilla developers that there are reasonable use cases for using PeerConnections in offline scenarios to drop that check in Firefox - although I would be concerned that it might run into another error further down in the code. Or you could try to submit a patch yourself.